# Error: "invalid operands to binary expression" while checking stringstream type

Tags: c++, wrapper

For academic reasons I am trying to build a Generic Wrapper.
This one owns one method to convert the `Wrapper` to string: `to_string`.

In order to be able to make the job when wrapped types are complex or custom, the class can take a lambda to "stringify" the value.

Because the lambda can be null, a check must be done to build the resulting string by the "natural way" or using the lambda.

But as soon as I wrap a complex type (eg: a struct), the pre-compiler (Xcode dialecte: GNU++17) reports an error.

Let's see the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <any>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
    using Stringer = string(*)(any);
    Stringer stringer;
public:
    T value;
    Wrapper(T value): value(value), stringer(nullptr) {}
    Wrapper(T value, Stringer stringer): value(value), stringer(stringer) {}
    void setValue(T value) { this->value = value; }
    string to_string() const {
        stringstream buffer;
        buffer << "(vtw)";
        if (stringer == nullptr) {
            buffer << value;      // << Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::stringstream' (aka 'basic_stringstream<char>') and 'const Coord')
        } else {
            buffer << stringer(value);
        }
        return buffer.str();
    }

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    using Coord = struct {int x; int y; };
    auto coord = new Wrapper((Coord){-105,245},
                                 [](any value)->string{ Coord value_ = any_cast<Coord>(value); stringstream buffer; buffer << value_.x << "," << value_.y; return buffer.str(); }
                                 );
    
    cout << coord->to_string() << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas how to work around it?

Comment: Both branches of a conditional must be valid, regardless of the value of the condition.

Answer (score 1):

`buffer << value;` must be valid, which it is not for your unnamed `Coord`. You could add a *`constexpr-if`* check to see if it supports streaming:

```cpp
    string to_string() const {
        ostringstream buffer;
        buffer << "(vtw)";
        if (stringer == nullptr) {
            if constexpr(can_ostream_v<T>) { // test here
                buffer << value;
            }
        } else {
            buffer << stringer(value);
        }
        return buffer.str();
    }
```

The `can_ostream_v` type trait used above could look like this:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
struct can_ostream {
    static std::false_type test(...);
    
    template<class U>
    static auto test(U) -> decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<U>(),
                                    std::true_type{});

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};

template<class T>
inline constexpr bool can_ostream_v = can_ostream<T>::value;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jxEvWca6q)

Comment: Thanks @Ted Lyngmo. Very well done. I didn't know the 'constexpr-if' expression.

Comment: @Luc-Olivier You're welcome! A _constexpr if_ statement is evaluated at compile time, so if the condition is `false` the following statement doesn't have to work. It requires c++17 though.  If you don't have C++17 you could make two separate overloads and use the type trait and `enable_if` resp. overload

Comment: I have C++17 so it works perfectly. Thanks you again.